# add start from constraint to a column in mysql

Tags: mysql

hey i am creating an application for invoicing(computer generated bill).
i have a table sales_log where ref no. column is set to auto_increment.i didnt assign the start value. i mean if the ref no. of 1st bill is 101 then i should automatically get 102..103...etc for the rest...i just dont know how to alter the table constraint and set a starting value for that column.
here is the description of my table

```
mysql> desc sales_log;
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| date     | date    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| item_id  | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| C_Id     | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| Quantity | double  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Ref      | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| price    | double  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-auto-increment.html

> To start with an AUTO_INCREMENT value
>   other than 1, you can set that value
>   with CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE, like
>   this:

```
ALTER TABLE sales_log AUTO_INCREMENT = 101;
```

Comment: looks correct but mysql> alter table sales_log ref auto_increment=100;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ref a
uto_increment=100' at line 1

Comment: "ref" does not belong there -

Answer (score 2):

To set the AUTO_INCREMENT back to 1 (for example), execute this:

```
ALTER TABLE sales_log AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

ALTER TABLE sales_log AUTO_INCREMENT = 101;

Answer (score 0):

`CREATE TABLE users (user_id  int NOT NULL, name varchar(50),PRIMARY KEY (user_id));`

`NSERT INTO users VALUES (1, 'Bob');`

`INSERT INTO users VALUES (2, 'Joe');`

`INSERT INTO users VALUES (3, 'Paul');`

`ALTER TABLE users MODIFY user_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;`

`ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT = 6000;`

`INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('Keith');`

`INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('Steve');`

`INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('Jack');`

`SELECT * FROM users;`

`user_id  name`

1        Bob
 2        Joe
 3        Paul
 6000     Keith

6001     Steve

6002     Jack